# Set up Fable on Windows and compile to Javascript

Tags: npm, f#, fable-f#

I want to start using F# instead of Javascript on a project (which is already established and has the backend done, but no frontend yet except for HTML and CSS).

I know relatively little about Node and few things about .NET but I have developed forms applications before. I have written many console apps in F# at this point but I hate both using and developing command line applications, I like GUIs so I'm desperate to start using F# in an actual project, but I just can't get it working. I have had numerous attempts where SAFE stack just failed while running an app (no code changes) and refused to rebuild, but .NET has been solid so far. What I want from this project though is a simple F# to JS complication. I've followed the instructions on the fable website and generated a project template, done `npm install` and built successfully but `npm start` always failed with command not found.

```
c:\fable>npm start

> SimpleFableApp@1.0.0 start c:\fable
> dotnet fable watch src --run webpack-dev-server

Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
```

**I just want to write an FSX file (or FSProj) and then compile it to a Javascript file I can include in the html.** I just something that will slot into my existing PHP project.

So I start a new .fsx file, put something simple like

`let x=10`

And then I want to compile that to a Javascript source, and I'm just going to need ground up instructions I think. I think I have installed the fable-compiler by using `npm-install fable-compiler` which does give the result of `+fable-compiler@2.13.0` (not sure if that's the latest).

Then apparently I should just run from the instructions I've found.
`fable path/to/your/project.fsproj`

which results in

`'fable' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

So obviously I have no idea what I'm doing!

Are there up to date instructions or troubleshooting steps somewhere that I'm missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fable` is a dotnet tool nowdays. Try this:

```
> dotnet new manifest
> dotnet tool install fable
> dotnet fable Test.fsx
```

This will produce the file `Test.fs.js`.

Comment: Wish that was mentioned in the "Getting started" section! Super easy, barely an inconvenience. Thank you!